# Adding missing hours to dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame where some of the hours in `Time GMT` are missing.
Normally, the hours should be shown in a sequence from 00:00 to 23:00, but sometimes an hour is missed.

Where an hour is missing in the sequence, I would like to insert a new row.
The new row will be a copy of the previous row, but with the following columns changed as follows:

- `Time GMT`: will contain the next hour of the previous row. i.e, if previous == 5:00, new == 6:00
- `Sample Measurement`: will contain the average between the previous value and the next value in Sample Measurement column.
- `MDL`: will contain the average between the previous value and the next value in column MDL

**What have I tried**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

class(hrOzone$Time.GMT)   # output type "character"

hrOzone %>%
  group_by(Date.GMT) %>%
  complete(Time.GMT = full_seq(01:24, 1), fill = list(count = 0))

head(hrOzone$Time.GMT, n = 100L)
```

DataSource url: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o1voBktR3i8ROt1Hp59OW5t3_uukIA3j/view?usp=sharing

**Date GMT**     **Time GMT**    **Sample Measurement**  **MDL**

01/03/2016        21:00:00       0.036                0.005
01/03/2016        22:00:00       0.035                0.007
01/03/2016        23:00:00       0.029                0.008
02/03/2016        00:00:00       0.03
02/03/2016        01:00:00       0.01
02/03/2016        02:00:00
02/03/2016        03:00:00
02/03/2016        04:00:00
02/03/2016        05:00:00
02/03/2016        **07:00:00**
02/03/2016        08:00:00
02/03/2016        09:00:00
02/03/2016        10:00:00
02/03/2016        11:00:00
02/03/2016        12:00:00
02/03/2016        13:00:00
02/03/2016        14:00:00
02/03/2016        **16:00:00**
02/03/2016        17:00:00
02/03/2016        18:00:00
02/03/2016        19:00:00
02/03/2016        20:00:00
02/03/2016        21:00:00
02/03/2016        22:00:00
02/03/2016        23:00:00
02/03/2016        00:00:00
03/03/2016        01:00:00
03/03/2016        02:00:00
03/03/2016        03:00:00
03/03/2016        04:00:00
03/03/2016        **06:00:00**
03/03/2016        08:00:00

**Update as per Waldi request**

```
> dput(head(hrOzone,20))
structure(list(State.Code = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), County.Code = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), Site.Num = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L
), Parameter.Code = c(44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 
44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 
44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L, 44201L), POC = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), Latitude = c(30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 
30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 
30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 
30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478, 30.497478), Longitude = c(-87.880258, 
-87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, 
-87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, 
-87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, -87.880258, 
-87.880258), Datum = c("NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", 
"NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", 
"NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", "NAD83", 
"NAD83"), Parameter.Name = c("Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", 
"Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", 
"Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", "Ozone", 
"Ozone", "Ozone"), Date.Local = c("2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", 
"2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", 
"2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", 
"2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", 
"2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02"), Time.Local = c("15:00", 
"16:00", "17:00", "18:00", "19:00", "20:00", "21:00", "22:00", 
"23:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", "05:00", "06:00", 
"07:00", "08:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00"), Date.GMT = c("2016-03-01", 
"2016-03-01", "2016-03-01", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", 
"2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", 
"2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", 
"2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02", "2016-03-02"), Time.GMT = c("21:00", 
"22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", 
"05:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", 
"13:00", "14:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00"), Sample.Measurement = c(0.041, 
0.041, 0.042, 0.041, 0.038, 0.038, 0.036, 0.035, 0.029, 0.026, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.028, 0.027, 0.025, 0.023, 0.025, 0.034, 0.036, 
0.038), Units.of.Measure = c("Parts per million", "Parts per million", 
"Parts per million", "Parts per million", "Parts per million", 
"Parts per million", "Parts per million", "Parts per million", 
"Parts per million", "Parts per million", "Parts per million", 
"Parts per million", "Parts per million", "Parts per million", 
"Parts per million", "Parts per million", "Parts per million", 
"Parts per million", "Parts per million", "Parts per million"
), MDL = c(0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.005, 0.005), Uncertainty = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Qualifier = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", ""), Method.Type = c("FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", 
"FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", 
"FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM", "FEM"), Method.Code = c(47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 
47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L, 47L), Method.Name = c("INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", "INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET", 
"INSTRUMENTAL - ULTRA VIOLET"), State.Name = c("Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", 
"Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama", "Alabama"
), County.Name = c("Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", 
"Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", 
"Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", 
"Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin", "Baldwin"), Date.of.Last.Change = c("2016-06-20", 
"2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", 
"2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", 
"2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", 
"2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20", "2016-06-20")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

Comment: Could you `dput(head(hrOzone,20))`? Downloading 1.9Gb of data is pointless.

Comment: @Waldi, I've just updated the question as you requested

Comment: If you look at this vector you'll see that ```6:00``` is missing. It goes straight from ```"05:00",``` to  ```"07:00"```  . Time.GMT ```= c("21:00", 
"22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00", "03:00", "04:00", 
"05:00", "07:00", "08:00", "09:00", "10:00", "11:00", "12:00", 
"13:00", "14:00", "16:00", "17:00", "18:00"), ```

Comment: OK ,thansk, got it!

Comment: What happens if there is no previous value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach using `zoo`'s `na.approx` for linear interplotation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

hrOzone %>%
  select(Date.GMT,Time.GMT,Sample.Measurement, MDL) %>%
  unite(datetime, Date.GMT, Time.GMT, sep = ' ') %>%
  mutate(datetime = ymd_hm(datetime)) %>%
  group_by(date = as.Date(datetime)) %>%
  complete(datetime = seq(min(datetime), max(datetime), 'hour')) %>%
  mutate(across(c(Sample.Measurement, MDL), na.approx)) %>%
  ungroup
```

For the data shared this returns -

```
#         date            datetime Sample.Measurement   MDL
#1  2016-03-01 2016-03-01 21:00:00             0.0410 0.005
#2  2016-03-01 2016-03-01 22:00:00             0.0410 0.005
#3  2016-03-01 2016-03-01 23:00:00             0.0420 0.005
#4  2016-03-02 2016-03-02 00:00:00             0.0410 0.005
#5  2016-03-02 2016-03-02 01:00:00             0.0380 0.005
#6  2016-03-02 2016-03-02 02:00:00             0.0380 0.005
#7  2016-03-02 2016-03-02 03:00:00             0.0360 0.005
#8  2016-03-02 2016-03-02 04:00:00             0.0350 0.005
#9  2016-03-02 2016-03-02 05:00:00             0.0290 0.005
#10 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 06:00:00             0.0275 0.005
#11 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 07:00:00             0.0260 0.005
#12 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 08:00:00             0.0300 0.005
#13 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 09:00:00             0.0300 0.005
#14 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 10:00:00             0.0280 0.005
#15 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 11:00:00             0.0270 0.005
#16 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 12:00:00             0.0250 0.005
#17 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 13:00:00             0.0230 0.005
#18 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 14:00:00             0.0250 0.005
#19 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 15:00:00             0.0295 0.005
#20 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 16:00:00             0.0340 0.005
#21 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 17:00:00             0.0360 0.005
#22 2016-03-02 2016-03-02 18:00:00             0.0380 0.005
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variation on linear interpolation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

data <- hrOzone %>% select(Date.GMT,Time.GMT,Sample.Measurement) %>%
                    mutate(date  = ymd(Date.GMT) + hm(Time.GMT)) 
             
data.extended <- approx(x = data$date,
                        y = data$Sample.Measurement,
                        xout = seq(from = min(data$date),
                                   to   = max(data$date),
                                   by   = 3600))

map2_dfr(data.extended$x, data.extended$y,
         ~(list(DateTime.Gmt=.x,
                Date.GMT=format(.x,"%Y-%m-%d"),
                Time.GMT=format(.x,"%H:%M"),
                Sample.Measurement=.y))))

# A tibble: 22 x 4
   DateTime.Gmt        Date.GMT   Time.GMT Sample.Measurement
   <dttm>              <chr>      <chr>                 <dbl>
 1 2016-03-01 21:00:00 2016-03-01 21:00                0.041 
 2 2016-03-01 22:00:00 2016-03-01 22:00                0.041 
 3 2016-03-01 23:00:00 2016-03-01 23:00                0.042 
 4 2016-03-02 00:00:00 2016-03-02 00:00                0.041 
 5 2016-03-02 01:00:00 2016-03-02 01:00                0.038 
 6 2016-03-02 02:00:00 2016-03-02 02:00                0.038 
 7 2016-03-02 03:00:00 2016-03-02 03:00                0.036 
 8 2016-03-02 04:00:00 2016-03-02 04:00                0.035 
 9 2016-03-02 05:00:00 2016-03-02 05:00                0.029 
10 2016-03-02 06:00:00 2016-03-02 06:00                0.0275
# ... with 12 more rows
```

Comment: Yeah, this is probably cleaner then having to do the merge part.

Comment: @Waldi, I run your code and it works. From what I can see, it creates a new dataframe with 2 new variables ```x``` and ```y,``` where ```x == %y/%m/%d : %hh/%mm/%ss```. But, I would need to modify in place ```hrOzone$Time.GMT``` to contain the complete sequence of hours.

Comment: See my edit for a possible solution with `purrr::map2_dfr`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

hrOzone %>% 
  expand(Date.Local, Time.Local=str_c(str_pad(0:23, 2, "left", "0"), ":00")) %>%
  left_join(hrOzone, by=c("Date.Local", "Time.Local")) %>%
  arrange(Date.Local, Time.Local) %>%
  mutate(Time.GMT = ifelse(is.na(Time.GMT), 
                           str_c(str_pad(as.character((as.integer(str_sub(lead(Time.GMT), 1, 2)) +
                                          as.integer(str_sub(lag(Time.GMT), 1, 2)))/2), 2, "left", "0"), ":00"), 
                           Time.GMT),
         Sample.Measurement = ifelse(is.na(Sample.Measurement), 
                                     (lag(Sample.Measurement) + lead(Sample.Measurement))/2, 
                                     Sample.Measurement),
         MDL = ifelse(is.na(MDL), 
                      (lag(MDL) + lead(MDL))/2, 
                      MDL)) %>%
  fill(everything(), .direction="down")
```

Answer (score 2):

Linear interpolation FTW, which should also account for the instance where you have consecutive missing values.

```
dtrng <- range(as.POSIXct(hrOzone$Date.GMT, tz="UTC") + 
         as.difftime(hrOzone$Time.GMT, format="%H:%M"))
dts <- seq(dtrng[1], dtrng[2], by="1 hour")

out <- merge(
  lapply(c(Date.GMT="%Y-%m-%d", Time.GMT="%H:%M"), format, x=dts),
  cbind(hrOzone, orig=1), all.x=TRUE
)

sel <- which(is.na(out$orig))
vars <- c("Sample.Measurement", "MDL")

out[sel, vars] <- lapply(out[vars], function(x) approx(x, xout=sel)$y)
```

Output:

```
#     Date.GMT Time.GMT Sample.Measurement   MDL orig
#1  2016-03-01    21:00             0.0410 0.005    1
#2  2016-03-01    22:00             0.0410 0.005    1
#3  2016-03-01    23:00             0.0420 0.005    1
#4  2016-03-02    00:00             0.0410 0.005    1
#5  2016-03-02    01:00             0.0380 0.005    1
#6  2016-03-02    02:00             0.0380 0.005    1
#7  2016-03-02    03:00             0.0360 0.005    1
#8  2016-03-02    04:00             0.0350 0.005    1
#9  2016-03-02    05:00             0.0290 0.005    1
#10 2016-03-02    06:00             0.0275 0.005   NA
#11 2016-03-02    07:00             0.0260 0.005    1
#12 2016-03-02    08:00             0.0300 0.005    1
#13 2016-03-02    09:00             0.0300 0.005    1
#14 2016-03-02    10:00             0.0280 0.005    1
#15 2016-03-02    11:00             0.0270 0.005    1
#16 2016-03-02    12:00             0.0250 0.005    1
#17 2016-03-02    13:00             0.0230 0.005    1
#18 2016-03-02    14:00             0.0250 0.005    1
#19 2016-03-02    15:00             0.0295 0.005   NA
#20 2016-03-02    16:00             0.0340 0.005    1
#21 2016-03-02    17:00             0.0360 0.005    1
#22 2016-03-02    18:00             0.0380 0.005    1
```

Comment: Very nice idea!